# Change forgotpassword layout - Gigya screensets

Tags: gigya

I want to change the Forgot password layout, means when a user enters an invalid email (and if he/she is unregistered). I want to display a message that the email is invalid and the user can click sign in below.

I am new to Gigya customizations, and looking forward to helpful replies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Forgot Password screen is easily customizable via the UI Builder.

See the documentation at https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/UI+Builder for information on how to use it.

Comment: Do you know where to add the screenID, if in case use does not add the correct emailID or if the emailId doesn't exist. As for successful submission, we add the screenId to this var - data-on-success-screen

Comment: @Harsheet I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you explain? What screenID are you trying to add?

Comment: If the user entered a wrong emailID or if the emailID is not registered, than I wanted to show a different screen. This is on forgot password flow. Thanks

Comment: Using JS, you could capture the response after the submit button is clicked. In the case where the emailID doesn't exist, Gigya returns errorCode 403047.
You would then call the accounts.showScreenSet method to present the user with the desired screen (e.g., Registration).